# How do I get Facebook to log me in each time so that I can debug the login process?

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator

The first time I log in using the Facebook SDK in my application, it remains logged in until I close out of Eclipse.

How do I force it to log me in each time so that I can debug the login process?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a logout via `Facebook.logout();`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your facebook page.
Under Accout/Privacy Settings
Go to Apps and Websites
From there you can remove your app and then it will require you to authorize next time you run it.