# about loging status of facebook +android

Tags: android, facebook

I am stuck at one point of Facebook.

I have used git API of Facebook to integrate Facebook on Android.

It is not asking for login in second time. I can login only once time not at the second time, i.e when I run the application for second time.

Please help me out for this problem, as I need solution ASAP.

Comment: Post some code, we can't help you fix what we can't see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Facebook to log me in each time so that I can debug the login process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028285/how-do-i-get-facebook-to-log-me-in-each-time-so-that-i-can-debug-the-login-proces)

Comment: Please do not re-ask the same question.  If you need to clarify your original, edit it to contain additional information.  Also, do not use textspeak appreviations here, try to use proper English when writing your questions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

it wll ask login one time only.Also check u have signout if it still won't works then i have remove that data of that application frm my emulator coz it wll store login in it's DB,so whenever you want's to login it will check in DB.

hope it might help 4 u.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement the logout funcation of the facebook sdk to logout from the Application. So now the application is always going to ask for the facebook userId and password.